# Getting rid of line breaks to create a table

Tags: r, formatting

I have a text file with long lists of text and numbers.  Each begins with text followed by 13 numbers but with a line break :

```
   TH227     0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00 
  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.27698E-21  0.00000E+00  9.27698E-21 9.27698E-21  0.00000E+00
```

I'm trying to use R to sort it into a single row with 14 columns and write it to a CSV file so it appears like this:

```
   TH227     0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.27698E-21  0.00000E+00  9.27698E-21 9.27698E-21  0.00000E+00
```

My R code is:

```
Input = read.table("input.txt", header=FALSE)
M = matrix(Input$V1, nrow=263, ncol=14)
write.table(M, "FormattedOutput.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=",")
```

I have 262 more rows of text and numbers, with similar line breaks.  When I try to run the above code in R Studio the resulting CSV file is a jumbled mess.  I'm trying to get rid of the line breaks from the input file, but R doesn't seem to strip them out.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a more elegant answer than this that would fix the issue during the read-in. But if you need something fast, here's one approach: just read in all your data and then column-bind the odd rows (on the left) to the even rows (on the right).

```
df <- read.table("your-file.txt", header=FALSE)
df_odd  <- df[1:nrow(df) %% 2 == 1, ]
df_even <- df[1:nrow(df) %% 2 == 0, ]
df_fixed <- cbind(df_odd, df_even)
```

You'll then probably need to cleanup the vector types of some columns (i.e., some columns that should be numeric will be stored as character).